# First time steeping!

Tags: extract-brewing, steeping, extract-plus-grains, body

I was advised by my LHBS that if I steep 500g of Carapils in 2L of water (for a 23-25L batch) at around 68°C, then use this as part of my boil, then I will have more body and head retention in my beer.

Is this method correct?

Do I use this 2L of water as part of the 11L *to be boiled* or do I add it to 9L of boiled water to reach the 11L boil size and then proceed as normal?

I use recipe builders as much as possible - do I need to worry about steeping efficiency when I am not trying to create fermentables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you use the wort you create by steeping as part of your boil volume.  The method looks fine.  I wouldn't worry about steeping efficiency.  You won't get more than a few gravity points out of it unless you steep several pounds of grain.  Also, be aware that not all grains are suitable for steeping.  Some need an actual minimash.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would be a protein rest, though the temperature is considerably lower than what I have heard before.  John Palmer, in his excellent book, says to use a temp between 113 and 131 degrees.   Here is the link http://www.howtobrew.com/section3/chapter14-4.html.   I have used this method quite a bit and seen a noticeable difference in the beer head retention.  Also you would definitely want to add this to your pre-wort boil.  You don't want to add anything to a post boil that hasn't been sterilized.